# In a list with unique pairs {A, B}, how can I sort them so that the last B is the first A in the next pair?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = {
{4.8, 1.2},
{7.3, 3.1},
{3.7, 2.8},
{9.6, 1.3},
{4.8, 8.7},
{1.2, 7.3},
{5.3, 4.8},
{3.1, 5.3},
{3.1, 3.7},
{2.8, 9.6},
{1.3, 4.8}
}
```

Result after ordering:

> {{3.1, 5.3}, {5.3, 4.8}, {4.8, 1.2}, {1.2, 7.3}, {7.3, 3.1}, {3.1,
>   3.7}, {3.7, 2.8}, {2.8, 9.6}, {9.6, 1.3}, {1.3, 4.8}, {4.8, 8.7}}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) and [`FindHamiltonianPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html):

```
rg = RelationGraph[#[[2]] == #2[[1]] &, list, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
hp = FindHamiltonianPath @ rg
```

> {{3.1, 5.3}, {5.3, 4.8}, {4.8, 1.2}, {1.2, 7.3}, {7.3, 3.1}, {3.1, 
>     3.7}, {3.7, 2.8}, {2.8, 9.6}, {9.6, 1.3}, {1.3, 4.8}, {4.8, 8.7}}

```
HighlightGraph[rg, 
   Style[DirectedEdge @@@ EdgeList @ PathGraph @ hp, 
         Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2],Red]]]
```

[image]